# Null instanceof Object

Tags: java, instanceof

I was trying on something and I wrote this code,

```
boolean x = null instanceof Object;
Object o = null; 
boolean y = o instanceof Object;
```

It's is no surprise both returned false. What surprised me was, IntelliJ IDEA complained `y` is always `false` but didn't say anything about `x`. Does this imply something?

Comment: What message did IntelliJ give, *exactly*? Perhaps it was hinting that although `null instanceof Object` is pretty clearly false, `o instanceof Object` is only false due to code analysis that it had performed - if you'd written the declaration of `o` significantly earlier, this could indicate a bug because you weren't intending a check on something that was guaranteed to be null.

Comment: Are you using y in any other condition? if so, then InterlliJ will report it because its not more an variable its just a plain `false`. You better should use `false` instead of such obvious value containing variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably just means that the IDEA code analyzier is not writtent to support this "use case". The analyzer is probably (intentionally) coded to detect the use of variables that have previously been assigned to `null`, since this is a quite common mistake to make while coding, but the `null instance of Object` case it not very common as very few programmers would write this while actually meaning something else.

There are many constructs like these that can not be correctly detected by static code analyzers like Sonar, Eclipse or IDEA. I would not worry much about it, just be aware that the IDE can not spot every mistake you make in your code.

Comment: So, no other implecations. HuH.